# How to tell Celery on what node to run the task?

Tags: python, celery, distributed-computing

Can i tell python's celery to run the task on the current node, or all nodes, and not on any random node, which is the default behavior?

Comment: If by node you mean worker, I think this can help you: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html.